# Odoo 8 - Launch modal on button click from web page

Tags: video, twitter-bootstrap-3, odoo, media, bootstrap-modal

I want to implement a feature on Odoo website such that there is a banner image onto which there is a play button. On click of the play button a modal should launch. The video link should be configurable on the play button. Is that possible in Odoo? I have been trying to do this but the modal does not get launched on button click.

Comment: Yes. the modal is getting launched through button. The modal has an iframe. I have to be able to set a link for the the iframe at the time of launch.

Comment: may be need to review the code, to understand better and check the possibility.

Answer (score 1):

In model with python

```
def update_func(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
.
.
```

in view with XML

```
<button name="update_func" type="object"
                            string="refresh" icon="gtk-refresh" />
```